# Unable to open plsql objects from Sql Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

We have two databases one for America's and one for Europe. I'm able to see the objects if i do pop up describe and if i click on the file in America's i can open it, but in EU i'm not able to ope it. It does not give any error back. 
Has anyone encountered issues like this ?

[image]

Comment: Can you show any code snippets?

Comment: 'click on the file?" What exactly are you trying to do in the database that isn't working?

Comment: I have added a image URL to my post.Please see if it helps

Comment: Have your DBA check your user's object privileges on both databases, it looks like you are missing some on the EU side.

Comment: so you're using the object search...if you navigate to that object in the connection tree instead, will it open?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, No the object isnt appearing on the connection tree. Even if i go with APPS user.  Looks like the user is not having privileges to view the file